# Publishing Site asking for credentials and shows the settings icon and edit link

Tags: publishing-site, site-contents

I have created a SharePoint Publishing Site and deployed it.

Now when I access a site, it asks for a login prompt and does not show the site content.

Comment: Can you please add screenshots if possible? It will be helpful for others to understand your question.